# Can we create a HD-Wallet with many sub-wallets but a single shared transfer()-method?

Tags: solidity, wallet-transfer, hd-wallets, wallet-contracts

Can we create a HD-Wallet-Contract with a `transfer()`-method for specific business-logic and make it inheritable or shareable for sub wallets?

Let's say we have this HD-Wallet and sum sub wallets that were created dynamically for our needs:

```
+ 0xHDWALLET
  - 0xsubwallet1
  - 0xsubwallet2
  - 0xsubwallet3
```

The HDWallet has a wallet-contract with a `transfer()`-method (and many other business logic implemented).

So, if one would send some Ether to `0xHDWALLET` it would pass the `transfer()`-method of `0xHDWALLET`-Contract.

But if someone would send some Ether to `0xsubwallet1` or `0xsubwallet2`, can we implement this wallet contract this way, that these payments would also went through the `transfer()`-method of the parent `0xHDWALLET` without to deploy new contracts with each new sub wallet?

Answer (score 2):

I think you’re asking if the subwallet addresses can “do something” other than just accept ether even if they are not smart contracts.

If that’s what you’re asking, then no. They can’t.

Non-smart-contract addresses (regular accounts) can’t “do” anything other than send transactions to other addresses or receive them.

If that’s not what you’re asking, let me know and I will withdraw this answer.

Comment: What we want to do is to offer sub-accounts underneath a big company account (which would be best a HD Wallet IMHO). All these sub accounts can receive Ether but would go through a one-time-deployed smart contract that will do further logic and checks like Whitelisting. Hope to be more clear now :)

Comment: As long as you have a smart contract in the mix at some point, then you can do anything you want. If there’s no smart contract, you can’t do anything other than receive or send either.